# Parse a custom file with a list of commands

Tags: c#, c++

There is a list of commands in a file that look like this:

```
command1 argument1 argument2
command2 argument3 argument4
```

And the result should look like

```
//Dictionary<command name,list of arguments>
Dictionary<string,List<string>>
```

Of course, there can be any amount of arguments, not just 2 of them. Parsing it is a piece of cake. But the thing is, there can be multi-line arguments.

```
command {some 
amount
of random text
} {and the second
argument} and_here_goes_argument_3
```

This is where it gets tricky. I've created a while loop with if conditions to parse this file, but it took me like 200+ lines of code and was totally unreadable. I bet there is a better way to do this.
Of course, I am not asking you to write the code for me. All I need is a basic approach. 
As for the language- it can be either C# or C++.

Comment: So an argument can be a single word separated by one or more spaces or a `{...}`?

Comment: Yup. And the {} block can contain basically anything.

Comment: Multiline regexes are a pain... I would discard this idea... So what remains is a little state machine probably. But it will be unreadable.

Comment: I was thinking about writing a function to convert this kind of file to XML first but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: I don't see how you can translate it to xml without parsing it. And if you parse it, then you already have the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing how much pain doing it with regexes would be:

```
string text = @"command1 argument1 argument2
command2 argument3 argument4
command {some 
amount
of random text
} {and the second
argument} and_here_goes_argument_3";

var rx = new Regex(@"^(?<command>(?:(?!\r|$)[^ ])*) +(?:(?<argument>{[^}]*}|(?!\r?$|{)(?:(?!\r|$)[^ ])+)(?: +\r?$?|\r?$))*", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

var matches = rx.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Command: {match.Groups["command"].Value}");

    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["argument"].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" - arg: [{capture.Value}]");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The problem is that this regex is both *unreadable* **and** *brittle*. Try adding a `x` just after the `argument}`, like `argument}x`. Handling malformed text is very difficult.

The only interesting part is that I use the `RegexOptions.Multiline` to handle multiple lines of text, and that `$` matches the `\n` but not the `\r` that I handle manually.

Paradoxically a small grammar using a library could be the "simplest" solution...

Ok now some "real" code:

```
private static readonly string[] commandDelimiters = new[] { " ", "\r", "\n" };

// We don't want the { to be used inside arguments that aren't in the form {...}
// Note that at this time there is no way to "escape" the }
private static readonly string[] argumentDelimiters = new[] { " ", "\r", "\n", "{" };

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string[]>> ParseCommands(string str)
{
    int ix = 0;
    int line = 0;
    int ixStartLine = 0;

    var args = new List<string>();

    while (ix < str.Length)
    {
        string command = ParseWord(str, ref ix, commandDelimiters);

        if (command.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"No command, at line {line}, col {ix - ixStartLine}");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            SkipSpaces(str, ref ix);

            if (IsEOL(str, true, ref ix))
            {
                line++;
                ixStartLine = ix;
                break;
            }

            if (str[ix] == '{')
            {
                int ix2 = str.IndexOf('}', ix + 1);

                if (ix2 == -1)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Unclosed {{ at line {line}, col {ix - ixStartLine}");
                }

                // Skipping the {
                ix++;

                // Skipping the }, because we don't do ix2 - ix -1
                string arg = str.Substring(ix, ix2 - ix);

                // We count the new lines "inside" the { }
                for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; )
                {
                    if (IsEOL(arg, true, ref i))
                    {
                        line++;
                        ixStartLine = ix + i + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }

                // Skipping the }
                ix = ix2 + 1;

                // If there is no space of eol after the } then error
                if (ix < str.Length && str[ix] != ' ' && !IsEOL(str, false, ref ix))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Unexpected character at line {line}, col {ix - ixStartLine}");
                }

                args.Add(arg);
            }
            else
            {
                string arg = ParseWord(str, ref ix, commandDelimiters);

                // If the terminator is {, then error.
                if (ix < str.Length && str[ix] == '{')
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Unexpected character at line {line}, col {ix - ixStartLine}");
                }

                args.Add(arg);
            }
        }

        var args2 = args.ToArray();
        args.Clear();

        yield return Tuple.Create(command, args2);
    }
}

// Stops at any of terminators, doesn't "consume" it advancing ix
public static string ParseWord(string str, ref int ix, string[] terminators)
{
    int start = ix;
    int curr = ix;

    while (curr < str.Length && !terminators.Any(x => string.CompareOrdinal(str, curr, x, 0, x.Length) == 0))
    {
        curr++;
    }

    ix = curr;
    return str.Substring(start, curr - start);
}

public static bool SkipSpaces(string str, ref int ix)
{
    bool atLeastOne = false;

    while (ix < str.Length && str[ix] == ' ')
    {
        atLeastOne = true;
        ix++;
    }

    return atLeastOne;
}

// \r\n, \r, \n, end-of-string == true
public static bool IsEOL(string str, bool advance, ref int ix)
{
    if (ix == str.Length)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (str[ix] == '\r')
    {
        if (advance)
        {
            if (ix + 1 < str.Length && str[ix + 1] == '\n')
            {
                ix += 2;
            }

            ix += 2;
        }

        return true;
    }

    if (str[ix] == '\n')
    {
        if (advance)
        {
            ix++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It is quite long, but I do think it is quite clear to read. The errors should be very exact (`line` and `col` given). Note that there is no possible escaping for the `}`. Doing it in an elegant way is complex.

Use it like:

```
var res = ParseCommands(text).ToArray();
```

Comment: So, I might end up using a library. Do you know a good one for that sort of things?

Comment: @HirasawaYui No... I haven't ever used grammars in my code, so I don't know.

Comment: where have `\r` came from? neither the question nor your test `text` doesn't have any. how simpler would be regex w/o it?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko The end of line can be \r\n or \n... It depends on the text editor.

Comment: I suppose you mean Windows, and even on Windows if you read a file in a text mode (default) OS will get rid of them automatically. Do you know of any cases generic enough (so there's a high chance OP will be affected even w/o mentioning them) when you need to deal with `\r` explicitly? I mean not text-based protocols like HTTP cos it would be worth to mention in the question. Otherwise I don't see any reason to over-engineer the solution

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Given his problem, he can't read it line by line (`StreamReader.ReadLine()` would remove all the end-of-lines). And I've just done a test: `File.ReadAllText()` returns `\r\n` if there is a `\r\n`.

Comment: so `text.Replace("\r","")`, and get rid of `\r` everywhere else

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Probably... with small differences. I decided to not consider an alone \r as an EOL, and consider it to be a character like any other, while for example the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method consider \r\n, \r, \n to be all EOL, and \r\n is a single EOL.